# Why did this character become a zombie after the King Crimson arc?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

Spoilers below.

After the fight with the boss, in the *Mystery of King Crimson* arc,

> Buccellati “dies”, and when Giorno arrives, his soul was leaving his body. Giorno healed his body and he resurrected, I think. After that, it is shown that his wounds don't show many, if not any at all, signs of blood or other types of harm.

In the *Green Day and Oasis* story arc, Green Day don't have any effect on Buccellati because

> the mold doesn't spread to dead things, **meaning that Buccellati body was dead but he still is alive.**

Well, for this question to be answered, I need to know what happened at the San Giorgio Maggiore church and how can Gold Experience resurrect someone.

Answer (score 1):

### My Explanation

It was fated by Rolling Stones in the last episode of *Golden Wind* (, [see here](https://jojo.fandom.com/wiki/GW_Episode_39),) that Bucciarati dies this way. In *JoJo*, resolve controls fate. Bucciarati's resolve was so strong that it was fated that even after he died, his soul inhabited his body. His body however is still dead. In the fan JoJo Wiki talking about Bucciarati's undead state, it says:

### Undead

During the events at San Giorgio Maggiore island, Bucciarati was given a lethal blow by the boss and was subsequently healed by Giorno's Gold Experience. Bucciarati eventually reveals that his life had ended at that time, however, his body continued to move only through the "life energy" that Giorno had given him. In this undead state, Bucciarati lacks bodily functions such as breathing, a heartbeat, or the ability to feel pain. However, it also allowed him to be immune to the effects of Green Day, and although the decay of his body gradually made him functionally blind and deaf, he could still converse with others through the ability to observe and feel what individual souls thought.
[If you want more information about Bucciarrati, look here for info](https://jojo.fandom.com/wiki/Bruno_Bucciarati)